# Why the solution of this brainteaser a linear function?

Tags: geometry, surfaces

I have been asked the following brainteaser:

> Imagine that you have a grid of dots in 2D placed at regular interval, you draw a convex shape by joining dots. Let us call M the number of dots touching the perimeter of your shape and N the number of dots contained inside the shape but not touching the perimeter.
>
> Can you find a formula function of M and N to compute this surface ?

The solution is a linear function of M and N, do any of you know why this function is linear as it was far from obvious for me that such a problem would be solved by a linear solution ?

(it can be proven that the solution will be linear and then using recursion you can extend this to any value of M and N but that does not give me an intuition of why this would be a linear function)

Comment: Please look at [Pick's Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) This does not require convexity. But convexity makes it clearer that we can triangulate.

Comment: Are you talking about a two-dimensional grid? If so, I agree on using Pick's Theorem. If not, it may be an interesting question. I don't immediately know if Pick's theorem is readily generalisable.

Comment: @HSN, I think it's pretty clear OP is talking 2-D. Pick's Theorem fails in $3$ (and higher) dimensions, as there are lattice solids with small volume and arbitrarily high numbers of lattice boundary points.

Comment: Yes sorry I was not clear about it being in 2D. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are talking about Pick's area formula

$$|A|=i+{b\over2}-1$$

here. The surprise consists in the fact that there is such a simple formula, but not in the fact that the number $i$ of interior points and the number $b$ of boundary points enter linearly. Any other exponents would produce wrong results under scaling of $A$ by integer factors.

Here is a proof of Pick's formula (there are dozens of them in the literature):

http://www.math.ethz.ch/~blatter/Pick.pdf